# How to fix “Violation of Families Policy Requirements” on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Same situation as
[How to fix “Violation of Families Policy Requirements” on Google Playstore StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438435/how-to-fix-violation-of-families-policy-requirements-on-google-playstore)

Our app only contains Vungle and Admob ads sdk, In app puchase.

And did not collect personal information.

We just used these permissions, and did not request permission at runtime.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
> ```

We have also added Privacy terms in the Play Console and url link in the App.

Many times we tried, but it was rejected every time.

Only receive emails with the same content.

[Rejected Email Content ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Ekn.png)

Google Play Team not able to provide any more information or a better answer to my question.

I'm really disappointed with Google for such poor support for developers too.

What What should we do next?

Thanks a million for any idea!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an application store's policy, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is in the screenshot you provided. Simply disclosing the fact you're collecting such information should be enough .

There's not much else I can provide without having access to the app & privacy terms.